# Menu Link not opening in new page in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have changed the settings in menu and appearance, and then open link in new tab/window for the ebrochure page but it doesn't open in a new page.

I tried it on the contact us page and it is working fine.

Is it because its a sub-menu or an ebrochure.

This is the embed code -

```
[embed width="600" height="480" target="_blank"]https://user-FmtnPJj.cld.bz/Pennine-Tools-eBrochure[/embed]
```

The ebrochure is working perfect but I cant seem to make it open in a new tab/window. I have tried and researched for a while now.

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ56c.png)

Comment: Ok so an update. I unclicked then mega menu, so now its working. But the styles of the sub menu seem to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me that link is opening in a new tab in FF and Chrome perfectly